# Why my reducer is adding new object to my redux store instead of changing current object values?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having problem with React-Redux, I want to update specific values in my store, but instead I'm getting new object in my store.

My action type:

```js
export const SENDMESSAGE = "SENDMESSAGE";
```

My action creator:

```js
export const updateContactFormData = (payload) => ({
  type: SENDMESSAGE,
  payload: payload
})
```

My initial state:

```js
export const formInitialData = {
  formShape: {...},
  formData: {...},
  formContactData: {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    text: ''
  }
}
```

And my reducer looking like this:

```js
export default function formReducer(storeData, action) {

  switch(action.type) {

    case SENDMESSAGE:

      return {
        ...storeData,
        [storeData.formContactData]: action.payload,
      }

    default:
      return storeData || formInitialData
  }

}
```

And now im getting new object in my store, as the Redux tool show:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh4pB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want update property value, not to define a new property using previous value as a name.

```
return {
    ...storeData,
    formContactData: {...storeData.formContactData, ...action.payload},
  }
```